# Git clone finish, but not deallocate MEMORY

Tags: docker, memory, memory-leaks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7a3j.png)

A simple script handle cloning source multiple times, which be handled on Docker. The question is Although git clone is finished, but RAM os container is not deallocate until I remove the folder code base.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blygo.png)

Comment: This is not something Git has any control over. Git does its work and finishes. It is *docker and your OS* (in co-operation) that decide how much memory is to be used. The memory isn't really *leaked* either, it's being used as a cache.

Comment: Hi @torek, Not sure why I remove folder code base, the memory deallocate and decrease to 40MB. If have any relationship between Memory and Directory ? As you suggest Cache as well. Beside that, I use alpine docker. Many thank.

Comment: Docker makes use of Linux's "user space" file system ([FUSE](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html)), which means that what look like file are actually stored in memory *in* the docker program, to whatever extent docker wants it to. That memory gets moved in and out of "real" and "virtual" memory in the usual way, which is where the OS comes in.

Comment: Tks for your suggest. It looks like come from docker mechanism: https://codefresh.io/blog/docker-memory-usage/. Problem not from Git.